# Scala - Playing a Sound -Beeping

Tags: scala, audio, beep

I am tryig to do something in order that to have a `beep` or `sound` for 2-3 minutes when a proces is done in my app. Currently I have this:

```
object SoundPlay {
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val bb = new ListBuffer[Any]

def main(args: Array[String]) {

   val beep = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.beep
   for (i <- 1 to 100) {
     bb += beep
   }

   bb.foreach(println(_))

  }
}
```

but this one makes only one sound and I can't make it repeated moe than Once.?!

### My UPDATE

I wrote this and is a kind of:

```
object SoundPlay {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
   for(i <- 1 to 10) {
     Thread.sleep(1000)
     java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.beep()
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: The important difference there is you've moved the `beep` inside the `for` loop. You could do that in your original example and you'd solve the immediate problem (only one call to the `beep` method). Both my and the other answer are a bit more of a general approach to handling methods like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beep` is a nasty side-effecting method. If you want to repeat it you'll have to capture it via something like scalaz `Task`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, concurrent.Task

val beepTask = Task(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.beep)
//traverse so we gather the 100 Tasks into a single Task
val bb = (1 to 100).toList traverse {_ => beepTask}
//everything is "lazy" until we call run, that's when the beeps actually happen
bb.run
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Imm, although I am not using the library `scalaz`, and I haven't use it before. I just did a small Update - up.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding to the `Buffer` the result of calling `beep` (which is `void`).
This means that the beep is made once as a side-effect and the void result is stored in the variable.

Probably you want to define an action that calls beep using a *lambda expression* or (as in the following code) [partially applying](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html) the beep function.

```
object SoundPlay {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  import java.awt.Toolkit._

  val bb = ListBuffer[() => Unit]() //a buffer of functions

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val beep = getDefaultToolkit.beep _ //this is a function with no arg
    for (i <- 1 to 100) {
      bb += beep
    }

    bb.foreach { case b =>
      println(b())
      Thread.sleep(500) // This pause is to hear the separate beeps
    }   

  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just wanted to repeat the `beep`s. I found a kind of functional option, it's in my UPDATE up. @pagoda_5b, Really thanks.